# In send multipart/form-data in javascript without xmlhtttprequest

Tags: javascript

In wso2 `XML HttpRequest` is not there, so how can I send  multipart/form-data?

Please explain. I tried with `XMLHttpRequest` but its throwing exception as it is not supporting.

Comment: Make a form with the said enctype.

Comment: can you please give an example